# Instruct shell script to do a task if the output of a program contains a specific word

Tags: bash, shell-script, pattern-matching

I need to create a program in Bash that launches a command, check if the result contain a word, and do something if it does.

Example: I need to check if a printer is online with

```
lpstat -p [printer name]
```

and if the result contains the word `inactive` the script should send me a mail.

How can I check a program's output for a word?

Answer (score 5):

This is a task for the mighty `grep`.

```
lpstat -p myprinter | grep inactive
```

will connect the output of `lpstat` to the input of `grep`, which will then print those lines that contain the string *inactive*.

To print the lines that contain the **word** *inactive* (i.e., *inactive* surrounded by spaces, commas and the like), you can add an option:

```
lpstat -p myprinter | grep -w inactive
```

However, you want to perform a test. You need to know that `grep` will generate an exit value of "success" (actually, it's a 0) whenever it does find the word. This can be used for testing. You are also not interested in the output of the `grep` command, just the success status. Let's therefore ask `grep` to be quiet, and wrap a test around it:

```
if lpstat -p myprinter | grep -q -w inactive
then
    mail -s "printer is inactive" othin
fi
```

Here is your reading assignment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html.

Comment: thank you very much bernbausch! i'll try now

Comment: @Othin if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.